# HDF5 how to handle empty rows

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I want to pass some values given by a MOCAP sensor to a hdf5 file. So, in order to simplify things, let's say I have a table like the next:

```
| time |  x1 |  y1 |  x2 |  y2 |
|    0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 |
|    1 | 2.1 | 1.0 | 2.3 | 3.1 |
|    2 | 2.4 | 1.4 |     |     |
|    3 | 2.2 | 1.5 | 2.4 | 3.1 |
|    4 |     |     | 2.3 | 3.2 |
```

I have some empty spaces because my sensor is not able to read information of certain body at certain time. So my question is, how can I handle in a single dataset this empty information?

By using *csv* format I can just ignore the information by just not writing any value between 2 commas. I'm using `h5py` with python. As a note, I have positive and negative numbers.

*Actually the question would it be if there's a better or more proper way other than putting `NaN` in the field.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are totally correct in using a `NaN`.

I would set a [fill value](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/H5P/H5Pset_fill_value.htm) and use that, in doing so I would use `NaN` or `None`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import h5py as h5

f = h5.File('test.h5','w')

ctype = np.dtype([('time','i'),
                  ('x1','f8'),('y1','f8'),
                  ('x2','f8'),('y2','f8')])

d = f.create_dataset('test', (5,), dtype=ctype)
d.set_fill_value = np.nan

data = np.array([(0, 2.0,    1.0,    2.0,    3.0),
                 (1, 2.1,    1.0,    2.3,    3.1),
                 (2, 2.4,    1.4,    np.nan, np.nan),
                 (3, 2.2,    1.5,    2.4,    3.1),
                 (4, np.nan, np.nan, 2.3,    3.2)],
                 dtype = ctype)
d[...] = data
f.close()
```

Then if we run it and look at the file it produces.

```
localhost ~$ ./test.py
localhost ~$ h5dump test.h5
 h5dump test.h5 
HDF5 "test.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "test" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
         H5T_STD_I32LE "time";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "x1";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "y1";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "x2";
         H5T_IEEE_F64LE "y2";
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 5 ) / ( 5 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): {
            0,
            2,
            1,
            2,
            3
         },
      (1): {
            1,
            2.1,
            1,
            2.3,
            3.1
         },
      (2): {
            2,
            2.4,
            1.4,
            nan,
            nan
         },
      (3): {
            3,
            2.2,
            1.5,
            2.4,
            3.1
         },
      (4): {
            4,
            nan,
            nan,
            2.3,
            3.2
         }
      }
   }
}
}
```

Of course you don't have to use a compounded data type, I just did as it kind of makes sense in your context.

Comment: Better late than never, sorry, I forgot to accept the answer. I think it was because it was the methodology I was already using at the time.